# Add Array Multiple Objects to [Any] in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to understand the best way to add multiple objects of different types to an `[Any]` array. This doesn't work in a playground in Swift 3, unless I explicitly cast the arrays and the objects in the arrays to `Any`.

```
var anyArray: [Any] = []
let strings = ["sup", "cool"]
let numbers = [5, 3]
anyArray += strings
anyArray += numbers
anyArray
```

It fails with the message - Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to expected argument type 'inout _'

Comment: the inout error has to do with pointers and reference types in swift... can you post the entire method that you are trying to do this in?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog this is the entirety of the code - it's in a playground.

Comment: @Alex You need to explicitly specify the type of array to `AnyObject`. `anyArray += strings as [AnyObject]`

Comment: The answer in the post that this was marked as a duplicate of was what I was looking for and is the correct answer to my question - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var arr = [Any]()
    let arr1:[Any] = [2,3,4]
    let arr2:[Any] = ["32","31"]
    arr += arr1
    arr += arr2
    print(arr)
```

Comment: So the error comes from trying to add `[Any]` and `[String]`?

Comment: This is really bizzare - I've tried this and the autocomplete suggests `contentsOf:` to me, but then the compiler says 'extraneous argument label contentsOf:' - as an error so I can't even compile with this. I'm on Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: make sure you're explicitly casting the arrays to [Any] or else the compiler will throw the "extraneous argument label" piece

Comment: Once you declare the types of `arr1` and `arr2` as `[Any]`, you can do `arr += arr1` (or `anyArray += strings` in OP's example). No need for `append(contentsOf:)`

Comment: made edits to match += syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another case of useless error messages from Swift's compiler. The real issue is that `AnyObject` means any *object* (reference type); structs -- which both `Int` and `String` are -- don't count because they are value types. If you want to refer to any type at all, use `Any`.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, but this doesn't solve the problem, the error message simply changes to be [Any] instead of [AnyObject]